# Rolls up the number of cases created within the last 30 days to the Account

Tags: apex, batch

Here's the requirement:
Rolls up the number of cases created within the last 30 days to the Account.

```
 global class ZW_BatchCaseNumberRollup implements          Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful{
     //Rolls up the number of cases created within the last 30 days to the Account
     //Account field: Number_of_Cases__c

     //Query: select Account.Id from Case where createddate=Last_n_days:30;
     global final String query;
     public Map<String,integer> CaseCount=new Map<String,integer>();
     global ZW_BatchCaseNumberRollup(String q){
         query=q;
     }

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{        
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);        
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope)
{ 

     Integer num=0;
     For(Case c : scope){
         String key=c.Account.Id;
         if(CaseCount.containsKey(key)){
            num=CaseCount.get(key)+1;
            CaseCount.put(key, num);
         }else{
            CaseCount.put(key, 1);
         }
    }
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    List<Account> accountsWithCases=[select Id,Number_of_Cases__c from      Account where Id in:CaseCount.keySet()];
For(Account acct: accountsWithCases){
    acct.Number_of_Cases__c=CaseCount.get(acct.Id);
}
update accountsWithCases;
}
```

My problem:

If I have a million Accounts, this class can not be used.
Question:

Can I change my query to an aggregate query?
How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
global class ZW_BatchCaseNumberRollup implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful
{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {        
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT AccountID, Count(Id) cnt FROM Case WHERE createddate=Last_n_days:30 GROUP BY AccountID]]);        
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<AggregateResult> scope)
    { 
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for(AggregateResult a : scope)
        {
            accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(id = a.get('AccountId'), Number_of_Cases__c = (Integer)a.get('cnt')));
        }
        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Aggregate queries have even lower limits, and generally do not work with batch Apex unless your query is one batch or smaller in size.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine up to 50 million records. Just keep in mind you'll want to not do gigantic DML operations, you'll need to break it down piece by piece.

Try to do everything you can inside the context of the execute method instead. I would probably switch what you're querying as well, make your scope be Accounts rather than cases.

Then, inside the execute method, query all of the cases associated with each account in the scope with an Aggregate query.

See here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

> A maximum of 50 million records can be returned in the Database.QueryLocator object. If more than 50 million records are returned, the batch job is immediately terminated and marked as Failed.